# Is it safe for a QObject's thread affinity to be a deleted QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

Consider the following code:

```
QThread *thread = nullptr;
QObject *object = nullptr;

void setup() {
    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    QObject *object = new QObject;
    object->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
}

void cleanup() {
    thread->exit(0);
    thread->wait(1000);
    
    if (!thread->isFinished()) {
        // handle error condition
    }
    
    delete thread;
}

void postEventToThread() {
    if (!object) { return; }
    QEvent *event = new QEvent(QEvent::User);
    qApp->postEvent(object, event);
}
```

If `postEventToThread()` is called after `setup()` and before `cleanup()`, then everything should work properly and an event will get posted to `object`'s event queue and processed in `thread`.

However, what happens if `cleanup()` is called before `postEventToThread()`?

In that case `object` still exists and is a valid object, but its thread has been deleted. Does `object` automatically start behaving as though it has no thread affinity? Or is this an error?

I tested it out and it doesn't seem to print any warnings, cause any crashes, or otherwise behave badly. But I want to check and make sure that deleting an object's thread (but not the object itself) and posting an event to it is allowed in Qt before I commit to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QThread starts the event loop by calling exec() and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread.

> However, what happens if cleanup() is called before postEventToThread()?

`thread` is deleted and it's event loop exits, all event processing for `object` stops.

> Does object automatically start behaving as though it has no thread affinity? Or is this an error?

In this case `object` is no longer associated with any thread. You can call it's methods from other threads, e.g main thread of application. Methods called directly on will execute in the thread that calls the method.

> But I want to check and make sure that deleting an object's thread (but not the object itself) and posting an event to it is allowed in Qt before I commit to it.

It's not disallowed but does not make sense. As I've wrote before, since after `object`'s thread is deleted, all event processing for `object` stops.

Comment: "It's not disallowed but does not make sense." The scenario I'm dealing with is when the app is quitting. Due to multiple threads running at once, it's possible that another thread will try to post an event to the object after its thread has been deleted. In this case it's fine that they're not processed because the app is quitting, but I just want to make sure it's not going to cause a crash.